# How can remove google map marker when I click the other button?

Tags: flutter

How can remove google map marker when I click the other button?

I used chip to realize function, but when I click other chip the data still display, how can clean before data when I click other chip?

```
changeType(String ctype) async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('Product')
        .where('type', isEqualTo: ctype)
        .get()
        .then(
      (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element) async {
          switch (ctype) {
            case 'AAA':
              markerIcon = await getBytesFromAsset(
                  'assets/aaa.png', 80);
              break;
            case 'BBB':
              markerIcon =
                  await getBytesFromAsset('assets/bbb.png', 80);
              break;
            case 'CCC':
              markerIcon = await getBytesFromAsset(
                  'assets/ccc.png', 80);
              break;
            case 'DDD':
              markerIcon = await getBytesFromAsset(
                  'assets/ccc.png', 80);
              break;
}

_markers.add(
            Marker(
...
...
...
icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerIcon!),
              infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                title: element.data()['Name'],
              ),
            ),
          );
```

if I click chip then the value is AAA, it's will show AAA data, but when I click BBB chip, it's will show AAA & BBB, how can do when I click other data then it's can clean data before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried to used

```
onPressed: () {
                                    removeGmapMarkers();
                                    changeType(e.campSiteType);
                                  },
```

then

```
removeGmapMarkers() {
    _markers.removeWhere((element) => true);
  }
```